# DBContext Filtering

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedArea))
            {
                using (dbContext c = new dbContext(dbContext.ConnectionString))
                {
                    c.CreateIfNotExists();
                    c.LogDebug = true;
                    MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = c.details.ToList();
                }
            }
```

I want to filter the contents in dbcontext and how do i do?
someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in this way

```
MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = c.details.Where(elem=> elem.Property==5).ToList();// returns elements with Property=5
```

I am assuming that your `details` has a property with name `Property` but you can use your fields e.g `.Where(elem=> elem.Name=='Peeter' && elem.Age > 30) //takes elements with Age > 30 and Name=Peter`